# RestFul API App Android

Tags: android, api, rest, authentication

I'm creating a login in an App Android. I have to pass the credentials to access and compare them to a MySQL database loaded in phpMyAdmin. To do this I created the API specifically for this log:

```
Route::post('/login', 'ApiController@login');
```

The next step is to connect the app and make it communicate with this URL. How do I connect? I found various codes but Android Studio tells me that their use is deprecated.

I have this piece of code. I would make sure that, in the else, so if the email and password fields are filled in, the app communicates with the API doing so Login. Can someone please help me? Place the code written so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b1, errore;
    EditText ed1,ed2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        errore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.errore);

        errore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if((ed1.length() == 0) && (ed2.length() == 0))
                {
                    errore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Logn with API
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably starting out Android development, and I suggest you look for libraries such as Retrofit, they make API transactions simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to send authentication POST request with username and password in message body.On server side, compare credential with database and send login success/failure flag as response. Handle the response accordingly in response.

Answer (score 0):

To make the process of using an API easier, it is often recommended to use a library to take care of the details for you. For example, try [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)

Then you can do something like:

```
// login code
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.api.com/login").execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>(){

@Override
public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception{
    // Do something with the Response
    // ...
    return response;
}

@Override
public void onThrowable(Throwable t){
    // Something wrong happened.
}
});
```